# не скрываются кнопки

Tags: python, tkinter

не скрываются кнопки `conf()` 
хотелось бы чтоб после нажатия исчезали настройки даты `dateSeting()`

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *   
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox  
import datetime
from datetime import datetime
import webbrowser
import keyboard
import os
import sys
# func
def hellp():
    webbrowser.open('https://web.telegram.org/#/im?p=@got4ikGRIFZ', new=2)
def pluseY():
    global dateYear1
    dateYear1 = dateYear1 + 1
    year.config(text=dateYear1)
def minY():
    global dateYear1
    dateYear1 = dateYear1 - 1
    year.config(text = dateYear1)
# 2 -------
def pluseM():   
    global dateMonth1
    dateMonth1 = dateMonth1 + 1
    month.config(text = dateMonth1)
    if dateMonth1 == 12:
        dateMonth1 = 0
def minM():
    global dateMonth1
    dateMonth1 = dateMonth1 - 1
    month.config(text = dateMonth1)
    if dateMonth1 == 0:
        dateMonth1 = 12

# 3 -------
def pluseD():
    global dateDay1
    dateDay1 = dateDay1 + 1
    day.config(text = dateDay1)
    if dateDay1 == 31:
        dateDay1 = 0
def minD():
    global dateDay1
    dateDay1 = dateDay1 - 1
    day.config(text = dateDay1)
    if dateDay1 == 0:
        dateDay1 = 31

# ================================================================
def conf():
    global year, pluY, miY, month, pluM, miM, day, pluD, miD
    global dateYear1, dateYear1, dateDay1, dateA, date
    year.pack_forget()
    day.pack_forget()
    month.pack_forget()
    pluY.pack_forget()
    pluD.pack_forget()
    pluM.pack_forget()
    miY.pack_forget()
    miD.pack_forget()
    miM.pack_forget()
    dateA = str(dateYear1) + ":" + str(dateMonth1) + ":" + str(dateDay1)
    date.config(text=dateA)

def none():
    pass
# =-=-=-==-===-==-===-==-=
def dateSeting():
    global dateA, date
    global year, pluY, miY, month, pluM, miM, day, pluD, miD
    global dateYear1, year, day
    global dateMonth1, month, dateDay1
    current_datetime = datetime.now()
    dateMonth1 = (current_datetime.month)
    dateYear1 = (current_datetime.year)
    dateDay1 = (current_datetime.day)
    year = Label(text = dateYear1)
    year.place(relx=0.485, rely=0.1)
    pluY = Button(text=(">"), width = 4, bd = 0, bg='#bdc3c7', command = pluseY)
    pluY.place(relx=0.535, rely=0.1)
    miY = Button(text=("<"), width = 4, bd = 0, bg='#bdc3c7', command = minY)
    miY.place(relx=0.435, rely=0.1)


    # ---------------------------------
    month = Label(text = dateMonth1)
    month.place(relx=0.485, rely=0.12)
    pluM = Button(text=(">"), width = 4, bd = 0, bg='#bdc3c7', command = pluseM)
    pluM.place(relx=0.535, rely=0.12)
    miM = Button(text=("<"), width = 4, bd = 0, bg='#bdc3c7', command = minM)
    miM.place(relx=0.435, rely=0.12)
    # ---------------------------------

    day = Label(text = dateDay1)
    day.place(relx=0.485, rely=0.14)
    pluD = Button(text=(">"), width = 4, bd = 0, bg='#bdc3c7', command = pluseD)
    pluD.place(relx=0.535, rely=0.14)
    miD = Button(text=("<"), width = 4, bd = 0, bg='#bdc3c7', command = minD)
    miD.place(relx=0.435, rely=0.14)

    # ----------------
    confirm = Button(text="Пременить", width = 15, bd = 0, bg='#bdc3c7', command = conf)
    confirm.place(relx=0.435, rely=0.165)
def expensesF():
    global dateYear1
    global dateA, date
    current_datetime = datetime.now()
    dateYear = str(current_datetime.year)
    dateMonth = str(current_datetime.month)
    dateDay = str(current_datetime.day) 
    addButton = Button(text="Добавить", width=10, bg='#bdc3c7',bd=0, height=1).place(relx=0, rely=0.05)
    item =   Entry(width=20, bd=0).place(relx=0.12, rely=0.05)
    dateA = dateYear+":"+dateMonth+":"+dateDay
    date = Button(text=dateA, width=10, bg='#bdc3c7', bd=0, height=1, command=dateSeting)
    date.place(relx=0.435, rely=0.053)
    num = Spinbox(width=15, from_=100, to=999999999999, bd=0).place(relx=0.29, rely=0.053)
    textNum = Label(text="Сумма:")
    textItem = Label(text="Причина:")
    textNum.place(relx=0.29, rely=0.03)
    textItem.place(relx=0.12, rely=0.03)
    expenses.config(bg='#2980b9')

def stat():
    messagebox.showinfo('Статистика', 'Долги -')
def save(): #сохранить
    messagebox.showinfo('Сохронино', 'Сохранение завершино')
    
def quit():#выход
    sys.exit()
    
    # -----------------------------
root = Tk()
root.geometry("750x900")
mainmenu = Menu(root) 
root.title("Таблица расходов")
root.configure(background= "#ecf0f1")
# menu
root.config(menu=mainmenu) 
filemenu = Menu(mainmenu, tearoff=0)
filemenu.add_command(label="Сохранить", command=save)
filemenu.add_command(label="Выход", command=quit)
helpmenu = Menu(mainmenu, tearoff=0)
helpmenu.add_command(label="Помощь", command= hellp)
helpmenu.add_command(label="Статистика", command= stat)
mainmenu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)
mainmenu.add_cascade(label="About", menu=helpmenu)
# ------------------------------------------------
# tegs
expenses = Button(text="Расходы", width=10, height=1, bg='#3498db', highlightthickness=0, foreground = "white", font=("Bahnschrift"), bd=0, command=expensesF)
expenses.grid(row=0, column=0)
earnings = Button(text="Доход", width=10, height=1, bg='#3498db', highlightthickness=0, foreground = "white", font=("Bahnschrift"), bd=0)
earnings.grid(row=0, column=2)
debts = Button(text="Долги", width=10, height=1, bg='#3498db', highlightthickness=0, foreground = "white", font=("Bahnschrift"), bd=0)
debts.grid(row=0, column=4)




# ---------------------------

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Можете добавить в вопрос чуть больше деталей, пожалуйста?

Answer (score 1):

чтобы убрать какой-то объект из окна TKinter нужно написать название и добавить метод destroy() к объекту который вы хотите убрать.
Например вот так:

```
def conf():
global year, pluY, miY, month, pluM, miM, day, pluD, miD
global dateYear1, dateYear1, dateDay1, dateA, date
year.pack_forget()
day.pack_forget()
month.pack_forget()
pluY.pack_forget()
pluD.pack_forget()
pluM.pack_forget()
miY.pack_forget()
miD.pack_forget()
miM.pack_forget()
dateA = str(dateYear1) + ":" + str(dateMonth1) + ":" + str(dateDay1)
date.config(text=dateA)
date.destroy()
year.destroy()
month.destroy()
day.destroy()
miY.destroy()
miD.destroy()
miM.destroy()
pluM.destroy()
pluD.destroy()
pluY.destroy()
```

Возможно есть вариант лучше, но я пользуюсь этим.